# How do I install Eclipse and Java SDK into Windows 10?

Tags: eclipse

Currenty on my desktop, I have two files as adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 and jdk-7u71-windows-x64, and I have windows 10 operation system. So could anyone explain me step by step what to do in order to execute eclipse.exe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SF.SE mertimiks. I've retitled your post to reflect what you've really asked, which is how to install Eclipse and the Java SDK into Windows 10. The first thing you need to do is install the Java SDK on your machine (jdk-7u71-windows-x64) by double-clicking on it as it should be an executable file. If it's not, extract it and run setup from within the root directory. Java support is provided at Oracle.com.

After rebooting, you'll need to extract the adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 file into a folder on your machine. Once you've done that, locate Eclipse.exe and create a shortcut for it and run it. There should be a "readme" file inside the root of the extracted folder, or one level in, with more explicit instructions. Eclipse support is provided at Eclipse.org.

Comment: Which location should I extract the adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702? Where should I locate Eclipse.exe?

Comment: You can extract it to wherever you'd like. To the root of your C: drive is a good place. Leave it there and expect to use it in that location. It will expand into a tree that you'll want to keep. You'll find Eclipse located inside it. Don't move Eclipse from within that structure. You could extract it to inside your Program Files folder, but when you do that, the path names can get rather long so I don't recommend it.

Comment: Okay, I extracted to C: drive, and created an Eclipse.exe shortcut on the desktop. I ran it normally and as an administrator, but both ways didn't work. Not any errors did come up. It just, nothing happens after I double click Eclipse.exe.

Comment: Since you're running Windows 10, I recommend you ask for support at [Eclipse - Getting Started](https://www.eclipse.org/users/) as that's where the documentation is and its a much more appropriate place to ask questions of this kind. You might also want to look at the readme inside the eclipse/readme folder.

Comment: Okay the video below solved my issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmspsMJhc9w